# netbeans dist folder jar not running

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans

I have a java program to insert from textfields data to an ms access database.
I am using Netbeans 7.4 java 1.7.
The program runs in the Netbeans but not in the dist folder(before some time it was running fine in both).I use the same libraries with other projects also which running fine in their dist folders but not this one with the database.
The current error is can not find  sun.jdbc.odbc driver and after that java.lang nullpointer exception error.Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: did you package it first before trying to run it from the folder? go on the Run tab and then build project, or just press F11.... or shift+F11 to clean it first... then run it from the generated file

Comment: yes i cleaned and builded it first and the main class is set correct.

Comment: and when you run it whats happening? maybe you need to update you java?

Comment: The current error is can not find sun.jdbc.odbc driver and after that java.lang nullpointer exception error when running from dist folder but in netbeans works fine.If i go to java 8 the jdbc-odbc is not suppported.

Comment: seems like its not supported either now, any chance your java got automatically upgraded, btw best way to test this send it a friend or to another pc of yours and run it from there...

Comment: also check out this question, maybe it has your answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264358/netbeans-not-building-the-lib-folder-in-the-dist-folder?rq=1

Comment: try this also, go to Libraries->Properties. The "lib" folder should be added as a library. remove it or remove them (several folders as libraries) and do clean and build. and tell if it helped  you

Comment: did you try all the stuff that are written on the answers of the question i linked you?

Comment: yes and the problem remains

Comment: wow man.... did you try it on another pc as i said? did you check if your java maybe got updated automatically????

Comment: thnx for your time

Comment: you are welcome man, sooo did you figure it out or what?

Comment: Fixed it.I saw from Control panel  that java 8 was installed maybe from some programs.Deleted java 8 and now jar is running correctly.

Comment: mannnnn i told you two times to check your java because maybe it got updated from another program..... I will just add it as an answer so the topic can close...

Comment: i only saw the links about library jars misplaced. :)

Comment: mannn next time read better :p :D im glad you solver the problem, keep up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, go to Libraries->Properties. The "lib" folder should be added as a library. remove it or remove them (several folders as libraries) and do clean and build.

If that doesnt help try checking your Java version because maybe it got updated automatically or by some other program.